# Extrinsic curvature using different coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis

I have some clarifications about the calculation of the normal vector and extrinsic curvature of a cylinder on pp. 25-26 ([gr-qc/0703035](https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0703035.pdf)),

The Euclidean metric in cylindrical coordinates $(r,\phi,z)$ is given by,

$$ds^2 = dr^2 + r^2 d\phi^2 + dz^2$$

A cylinder embedded in Euclidean space is given by the constraint $S = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} - a = r -a \,$ where $a$ is some fixed radius.

The metric is $g_{\mu\nu} = \rm{diag}(1,r^2,1)$ and $\gamma_{\mu\nu} = \rm{diag}(a^2,1)$ is the induced metric.

The normal vector is given by,

$$n^\mu = g^{\mu\nu} \nabla_\nu S$$

The normal vector in Cartesian coordinates it is (*pardon the notation*),

$$n^\mu = \left(\frac{x}{a},\frac{y}{a},0 \right)$$

while in cylindrical coordinates

$$n^\mu = (1,0,0)$$

The extrinsic curvature $K_{ij}$ is given by

$$K_{ij} = -\nabla_\beta n_\alpha (\partial_i)^\alpha (\partial_j)^\beta$$

The trace of $K_{ij}$ is given by,

$$K = \gamma^{ij} K_{ij}$$

Also note that,

$$\nabla_\beta n_\alpha = g_{\alpha \sigma} \nabla_\beta n^\sigma$$

In Cartesian coordinates,

$$\nabla_\beta n^\alpha = \rm{diag} (a^{-1},a^{-1},0)$$

which leads to the trace $K = -a^{-1}$ (I didn't go to the details since this is a standard calculation that is not part of my question).

Now, in cylindrical coordinates

$$\nabla_\beta n^\alpha = \partial_\beta n^\alpha + \Gamma^{\alpha}_{\sigma \beta} n^\sigma$$

where the first term vanishes since $n^\alpha = (n^r, n^\phi, n^z) = (1,0,0)$. Now since only $n^r = 1$ has a nonzero value,

$$\nabla_\beta n^r = \Gamma^{r}_{r \beta} n^r$$

The Christoffel symbol is given by,

$$\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu \nu} = \frac{1}{2} g^{\lambda \sigma} \left( \partial_\mu g_{\nu \sigma} + \partial_\nu g_{\sigma \mu} - \partial_\sigma g_{ \mu \nu} \right)$$

Thus,

$$\Gamma^{r}_{r \beta} = \frac{1}{2} g^{rr} \partial_\beta g_{rr}$$

Since $g_{rr} = 1$, this will defintely lead to $K=0$.

My question is, how can the $K$ have different values by using different coordinates to calculate it?

Comment: I do not follow your computations at all. Since the surface is a $2$-dimensional manifold, your computation should be in two dimensions, not in three. You cannot work in the coordinates of the ambient space.

Comment: @TedShifrin I corrected the typo w/c should include the $z$ component, and I added the reference on the top.

Comment: No, that “correction” is wrong. I am not interested in the reference. My original comment stands.

Comment: @TedShifrin How can that happen if the cylinder is embedded in 3d space? The normal vector has three components.

Comment: Read some basic differential geometry texts. The Gauss (normal) map maps the surface to the sphere, and so its derivative maps the tangent plane of the surface to the tangent plane of the sphere at the appropriate point, so in fact you have a self-adjoint map,of the tangent plane of the surface to itself.